# PayPal's CallPaymentDetails function

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-nvp

I downloaded paypalplatform.php, can't remember where from, but it gives me a nice little function which allows me to check the state of a payment:

```
CallPaymentDetails( $payKey, $transactionId, $trackingId );
```

This returns lots of useful data like `status` and `paymentInfoList.paymentInfo(0).transactionStatus` and much more.

I know I can write lots of `if` statements to try to account for all the values returned to me when I call `CallPaymentDetails`, which I feel can be very error prone, or it could result in me over looking a scenario.

So my question is, does a sample template exist which takes all values into consideration, i.e. so I don't have to re-invent the wheel, which takes care of all scenarios?

For example, at the moment I have:

```
$resArray = CallPaymentDetails( $payKey, $transactionId, $trackingId );

if(strtoupper($resArray["responseEnvelope.ack"]) == "SUCCESS") {

    if(strtoupper($resArray["status"]) == "CREATED") {

        // do something

    } elseif(strtoupper($resArray["status"]) == "EXPIRED") {

        // do something

    } elseif(strtoupper($resArray["status"]) == "COMPLETED") {

        // do something

        if(strtoupper($resArray["paymentInfoList.paymentInfo(0).transactionStatus"]) == "PENDING") {

            // do something

        } elseif(strtoupper($resArray["paymentInfoList.paymentInfo(0).transactionStatus"]) == "FAILED") {

            // do something

        } else {

            // what other value could be returned

        }

    } else {

        // what other value could be returned

    }

} else {

    // what other value could be returned

}
```

If I try to do all the variables, I could be at this forever trying to capture all scenarios, which is why I was wondering if such a template already exists which caters for all scenarios via if statements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't grab a file on the internet like `paypalplatform.php`.

[Paypal use Github](https://github.com/paypal) a lot to share all APIs for all differents languages. I really recommend you to take a look at some repository such as :

- [merchant-sqk-php](https://github.com/paypal/merchant-sdk-php)
- [sdk-core-php](https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-php)
- [codesample-php](https://github.com/paypal/codesamples-php)
- [adaptivepayments-sdk-php](https://github.com/paypal/adaptivepayments-sdk-php)

The last two are interesting for you. They both provide useful code sample for your case.

**codesamples-php**

It presents a [simple call](https://github.com/paypal/codesamples-php/blob/master/AdaptivePayments/sample/code/PaymentsDetails.php) to the function you mention and describes all return message that can be found using one variable `$response->status`. Comments reveal all case this variable can have:

```
if ($response->responseEnvelope->ack == "Success")
{

  // The status of the payment. Possible values are:
  //
  // * CREATED - The payment request was received; funds will be
  // transferred once the payment is approved
  // * COMPLETED - The payment was successful
  // * INCOMPLETE - Some transfers succeeded and some failed for a
  // parallel payment or, for a delayed chained payment, secondary
  // receivers have not been paid
  // * ERROR - The payment failed and all attempted transfers failed
  // or all completed transfers were successfully reversed
  // * REVERSALERROR - One or more transfers failed when attempting
  // to reverse a payment
  // * PROCESSING - The payment is in progress
  // * PENDING - The payment is awaiting processing
  $logger->log("Payment Status : ".$response->status);
}
```

**adaptivepayments-sdk-php**

It presents [a more detailed example](https://github.com/paypal/adaptivepayments-sdk-php/blob/master/samples/PaymentDetailsReceipt.php) on how to use your function. It takes values from an html form, easier to test it. Like the previous example, we can see same states returned by the API:

```
$ack = strtoupper($response->responseEnvelope->ack);
if($ack != "SUCCESS"){
  echo "<b>Error </b>";
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($response);
  echo "</pre>";
} else {
/*
 *       The status of the payment. Possible values are:

       * CREATED - The payment request was received; funds will be
       transferred once the payment is approved
       * COMPLETED - The payment was successful
       * INCOMPLETE - Some transfers succeeded and some failed for a
       parallel payment or, for a delayed chained payment, secondary
       receivers have not been paid
       * ERROR - The payment failed and all attempted transfers failed
       or all completed transfers were successfully reversed
       * REVERSALERROR - One or more transfers failed when attempting
       to reverse a payment
       * PROCESSING - The payment is in progress
       * PENDING - The payment is awaiting processing
 */
  echo "<table>";
  echo "<tr><td>Ack :</td><td><div id='Ack'>$ack</div> </td></tr>";
  echo "<tr><td>PayKey :</td><td><div id='PayKey'>$response->payKey</div> </td></tr>";
  echo "<tr><td>Status :</td><td><div id='Status'>$response->status</div> </td></tr>";
  echo "</table>";
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($response);
  echo "</pre>";
}
```

**In both case**, you only need a simple switch/case to handle response state. Something like that:

```
switch ($status)
{
  case 'CREATED':
    // handle CREATED state
    break;
  case 'COMPLETED':
    // handle COMPLETED state
    break;
  case 'INCOMPLETE':
    // handle INCOMPLETE state
    break;
  case 'ERROR':
    // handle ERROR state
    break;
  case 'REVERSALERROR':
    // handle REVERSALERROR state
    break;
  case 'PROCESSING':
    // handle PROCESSING state
    break;
  case 'PENDING':
    // handle PENDING state
    break;

  default:
    throw new Exception(sprintf("State '%s' isn't handle.", $status));
}
```